# How to Find largest list in 2d lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to return longest list within list in the sense that it is the longest list in length and if their are more then 1 list of same size then the comparison will be made according to the elements within that list.

Comment: And what's the specific problem with your attempt to implement that?

Comment: Can you add your code ? Im not worker..., only can make a suggestion in your code, add the code you are trying so far.

Comment: Suppose this is a list:-[[2, 3, 5, 8], [2, 13, 15], [3, 5, 8, 13], [5, 3, 8], [5, 8, 13], [8, 5, 13]] i want to print [2,3,5,8] because its largest in size and its element are smaller than [3,5,8,13]

Comment: [Edit] the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l = [[2, 3, 5, 8], [2, 13, 15], [3, 5, 8, 13], [5, 3, 8], [5, 8, 13], [8, 5, 13]]

print(min(l, key=lambda k: (-len(k), k)))
```

Prints:

```
[2, 3, 5, 8]
```

Comment: [2, 3, 5, 8] >= [3, 5, 8, 13] => False

Comment: @RonaldAaronson Op states in comments _"...i want to print `[2,3,5,8]` because its largest in size and its element are smaller than `[3,5,8,13]`"_

Comment: I stand corrected. I was just looking at the problem description where it was stated, "and if their are more then 1 list of same size then the comparison will be made according to the elements within that list." Sometimes you have to read all the comments that come later. Of course, it would not have hurt to have stated the problem clearly the first time -- but no excuse!

Comment: @RonaldAaronson No problem :) I've got it wrong first time too, then read again the comments section.